# General proof sufficency

Tags: logic

this is my first post here and hopefully I'm doing this correctly. Suppose I have a problem **X**, and the group of elements **Y** represent the possible solutions to problem **X**.

I'm trying to prove that an element *d* solves **X**, which would mean *d* $\in$ **Y** (*d* is in the set of solutions **Y** of **X**) and I know the following:

- If condition *A* is not met, then without a doubt *d* $\notin$ **Y**
- If condition *B* is not met, then without a doubt *d* $\notin$ **Y**

But how would I go about proving that if both conditions *A* and *B* are met, then that is sufficient to acertain that *d* $\in$ **Y** ?

It is a bit of a very generic question and I apologize for that, but a book recommendation or a guideline on where to begin tackling something of this nature would be very helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: More details would help - like a particular kind of property or specific example. This question seems too general to have a useful answer - I'm a bit confused by the question since, in general, showing that a candidate solution satisfies two necessary conditions is not sufficient. Narrowing down your question will help answerers write something that's useful to you - even if you only use an example to illustrate the idea you're after and still ask a more broad question.

Comment: What even are the conditions $A$ and $B$? I agree with @MiloBrandt, we need more informations.

Answer (score 1):

It is not (in general) true.

The statement $P \implies Q$ is logically equivalent to

the statement $\neg Q \implies \neg P$.

However, it is **not** logically equivalent to the statement

$Q \implies P$.

Let $D$ represent the statement $d \in Y.$

Then you have

$\neg A \implies \neg D$ and $\neg B \implies \neg D$

This means that you have

$D \implies (A \wedge B).$

But you **want**

$(A \wedge B) \implies D$.

You can't get there.